# Qt : Transfer an event to a child widget without infinite recursion

Tags: qt, events, widget

I would like to transfer an event to a child of one widget.
My current implementation is (where `_table` is a `QTableWidget*` data member of `MyWidget`)

```
void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)  
{  
    QHeaderView *headerview = _table->horizontalHeader();
    QPoint headerpoint = headerview->mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos());
    const int index = headerview->logicalIndexAt(headerpoint);
    if ((index >= 0) && (index < headerview->count())) {
        QApplication::postEvent(headerview, new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, headerpoint, event->button(), event->buttons(), Qt::NoModifier));
    }
    QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);  
}
```

The problem is that this implementation seems to produce an infinite loop or recursion.

What would be a correct implementation ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to make sure you mark the `event` as `accepted` i.e.:

`event->setAccepted( true );`

or

`event->accept();`

other as per the docs "Setting the accept parameter indicates that the event receiver wants the event. **Unwanted events might be propagated to the parent widget.**"

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qevent.html#accepted-prop